# Why does naturalHeight or naturalWidth return `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

My class assignment wants me to use the `defer` tag for the script I am referencing, but this leads to the image's `naturalWidth` being undefined due to the order of execution in my js file.

My HTML has this line in the head (assignment wants me to put it in the `<head>` but use `defer="defer"`)
`<script src="scripts/script.js" defer="defer"></script>`

My js:

```
var catImageWidth = document.getElementById("cat-image").naturalWidth;
var birdImage = document.getElementById("bird-image");
birdImage.width = catImageWidth;
```

So I tried this:

```
var catImage = document.getElementById("cat-image");
var birdImage = document.getElementById("bird-image");
var catImageWidth;

catImage.onload = function() {
    catImageWidth = this.naturalWidth;
    console.log(catImageWidth) //logs 600
}

birdImage.width = catImageWidth; //logs `undefined`
```

I think that the assignment of `birdImage.width` is undefined because this line of code runs before `catImage.onload` actually happens. Does this mean that I'm slave to assigning `birdImage.width` within the scope of  the `function` of `catImage.onload`?

P.S. I tried ES6 of `catImage.onload = () => { //block of code }` but this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to access a variable out of scope.

Please give this a try:

```
<img id="cat-image" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg">
<img id="bird-image" src="http://animalia-life.club/data_images/bird/bird3.jpg">

<script>
var catImage = document.getElementById("cat-image");
var birdImage = document.getElementById("bird-image");
var catImageWidth;

catImage.onload = function() {
    catImageWidth = this.naturalWidth;
    birdImage.width = catImageWidth;
}

console.log(birdImage.width);
</script>
```

Comment: that is what I have, as shown above in my question. So I'm not sure why it actually doesn't `defer`.

Comment: Please look at my solution carefully. You will see what the difference is. Also, I encourage you to try my code so you can understand the difference. You can copy and paste that code and run it.

Comment: cheers, that's what I originally did, as I had `birdImage.width = catImageWidth;` within the function. I believe defer doesn't wait for image assets, however

Comment: @simmonson Awesome! I am glad I could help. Would you choose this as your Best Answer? Please also feel free to vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that I'm slave to assigning `birdImage.width` within the scope of the function of `catImage.onload`?

Seems so, that's the best way to do it.

You can use an arrow function, but not with the `this` keyword to reference the image.

**Doesn't work:**

```
catImage.onload = () => {
    catImageWidth = this.naturalWidth; //undefined
    console.log(catImageWidth)
}
```

Because in arrow function the `this` object doesn't bind to the image  reference, it references the outer scope's `this`.

**Does work:**

```
catImage.onload = function() {
    catImageWidth = this.naturalWidth;
    console.log(catImageWidth) //logs 600
}
```

**Or:**

```
catImage.onload = function() {
    catImageWidth = catImage.naturalWidth;
    console.log(catImageWidth) //logs 600
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as well, using JQuery (note that I save the element reference first (I am working with a JS class that maintains this element), then I need to properly get to the object that holds the `naturalWidth` within the `onLoad` function:

Get reference once DOM is built:

```
this._imageElement = $(this._htmlElement).find("img.theImage:first");
$(this._imageElement).on('load', this._onImageLoaded.bind(this));
```

The later:

```
_onImageLoaded() {
   this._imageWidth = this._imageElement[0].naturalWidth;
   this._imageHeight = this._imageElement[0].naturalHeight;
}
```